# Change PHP code to JS

Tags: javascript, php, post, sum

Hello I have a code in PHP that catches some values inserted in other page and it adds all values and in the next page it shows the "total" and I want to know if is it possible to make the same function of this code in JavaScript.

```
<?php

  $ak1 = $_POST['ak1'];
  $ak2 = $_POST['ak2'];
  $ak3 = $_POST['ak3'];
  $ak4 = $_POST['ak4'];
  $ak5 = $_POST['ak5'];
  $ak6 = $_POST['ak6'];
  $ak7 = $_POST['ak7'];

  //CS AK

  $akcs1 = $_POST['akcs1'];
  $akcs2 = $_POST['akcs2'];
  $akcs3 = $_POST['akcs3'];
  $akcs4 = $_POST['akcs4'];
  $akcs5 = $_POST['akcs5'];
  $akcs6 = $_POST['akcs6'];
  $akcs7 = $_POST['akcs7'];

?>
<?php


echo '<p><i>Sent at:</i>';
echo date('H:i, jS F');

$total = 0;

$total = $ak1 + $ak2 + $ak3 + $ak4 + $ak5 + $ak6 + $ak7 + $akcs1 + $akcs2 + $akcs3 + $akcs4 + $akcs5 + $akcs6 + $akcs7;

echo '<br><br><br><strong>Total: </strong>'.$total;

echo '<hr width="20%">';

if( $total == 0)
{
  echo '<br><br><strong>You did not make any order</strong>';
}

$value = 0.00;

define('ak1p', 140);
define('ak3p', 160);
define('ak4p', 120);
define('ak5p', 180);
define('ak6p', 210);
define('ak7p', 250);
define('ak2p', 285);

define('ak1csp', 120);
define('ak3csp', 200);
define('ak4csp', 110);
define('ak5csp', 110);
define('ak6csp', 130);
define('ak7csp', 200);
define('ak2csp', 300);

$value =      $ak1 * ak1p
            + $ak3 * ak3p
            + $ak4 * ak4p
            + $ak5 * ak5p
            + $ak6 * ak6p
            + $ak7 * ak7p
            + $ak2 * ak2p
            + $akcs1 * ak1csp
            + $akcs3 * ak3csp
            + $akcs4 * ak4csp
            + $akcs5 * ak5csp
            + $akcs6 * ak6csp
            + $akcs7 * ak7csp
            + $akcs2 * ak2csp;

echo '<strong>Total to pay: </strong><font face color="green">'.$value.'</font><strong> $</strong>'; 


?>
```

Comment: Yes it is eminently possible. You might even get a Rep hungry member to do it for you if you wait a while

Comment: Needs More Focus. Volunteers are not expected to translate scripts from one language to another -- especially when there are multiple aspects and no legitimate effort / coding attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, let's look at the code you posted.

I think it would help to refactor this code into a more logical sense before attempting this in Javascript.  That should make it easier to transpose. Every time there is repetition of similar code (e.g. `$ak1 = $_POST['ak1']; $ak2 = $_POST['ak2']; ...` ) I would think there must be a more efficient way of getting your programming language to do the hard work. Computers are good at repetitive tasks after all.

I assume you have labelled all of the input fields in your form individually but you can actually pass them to `$_POST` as arrays if you give them all the same name and append square brackets like so:

```
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">
<input type="text" name="ak[]">

<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
<input type="text" name="akcs[]">
```

I don't know why you have two different sets of names for the input fields - it might help to merge these into one unless you have a good reason not too.

Now you have the HTML in a more maintainable format, you can seriously cut down on the amount of variable assignment that is needed in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ak'], $_POST['akcs'])){
  extract($_POST);
  $all_fields = array_merge($ak, $akcs);
  $total = array_sum($all_fields);
  if($total){
    echo "<p><i>Sent at:</i>" . date('H:i, jS F');
    $ak_values   = [140, 285, 160, 120, 180, 210, 250, 120, 300, 200, 110, 110, 130, 200];
    $value = array_sum(array_map(function($a, $b){
      return $a * $b;
  }, $all_fields, $ak_values));
    echo '<br><br><br><strong>Total: </strong>'.$total;
    echo '<hr width="20%">';
    echo '<strong>Total to pay: </strong><font face color="green">'.$value.'</font><strong> $</strong>';
  } else {
  echo '<br><br><strong>You did not make any order</strong>';
  }
}
```

Making use of PHP's features such as [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (which is necessary to combine the two sets of input fields in your form - see? You know it makes sense to only have the one type ;) ) makes it much less repetitive and also more maintainable should you wish to amend the form at a later date.

So how does this convert to JavaScript?

I'm glad you asked.

```
var ak_values   = [140, 285, 160, 120, 180, 210, 250, 120, 300, 200, 110, 110, 130, 200];
var order_date = document.getElementById('order_date');
var message = document.getElementById('message');
function sum(a,b){ return a+b }
document.getElementById('sum').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var ak = [];
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name="ak[]"], [name="akcs[]"]')).forEach(function(i){
    ak.push( i.value === "" ? 0 : parseInt(i.value));
});
  var total = ak.reduce(sum);
  if (total){
    order_date.innerHTML =  "<i>Sent at:</i>" + new Date();
    ak = ak.map(function(item, index){
      return item * ak_values[index];
    });
    var value = ak.reduce(function(sum, item){
      return sum + item;
    });
    message.innerHTML = '<br><br><br><strong>Total: </strong>' + total + '<hr width="20%"><strong>Total to pay: </strong><font face color="green">' + value  + '</font><strong> $</strong>';
  } else{
    message.innerHTML = '<br><br><strong>You did not make any order</strong>';
  }
});
```

Javascript has comparable functions for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the array sum etc. and you can see how taking the approach in PHP to use such standard functions makes it easier to translate in to another language.

A few things to consider:

- Do you want these sorts of calculations to occur in the browser? The prices presumably would be stored in a database which would need to be retrieved
- The user can manipulate values (like the ones stored in the `var ak_values` array) in Javascript
- Using AJAX might be better?
- Inline styles?

Here is a (slightly ugly) but working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/codebubb/3tht5y8v/1/

Comment: I made the php code to open directly from localhost but in this moment I cant access localhost to I tryed to find an other way to keep working on my code.  You helped a lot, thank you very mutch !

Comment: You're welcome. You can always start up a PHP dev server in any directory with `php -S localhost -t .` and then browsing to http://localhost/script name.php if that's the issue.